# jQuery fadeIn fadeOut makes page scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, fadein, fadeout

I have wordpress enabled website where I want to create a featured block.  This featured block will have featured articles fading one after another.  I got it working by using the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` APIs of jQuery, but there is a problem with the implementation.

Here is the code I have -

```
var count=0;
var sticky_count=<?php echo count($sticky);?>;

jQuery(document).ready(featured_block);

function featured_block() {   
    jQuery(".featured" + count % sticky_count).delay(5000).fadeOut(callback);
}

function callback() {
    count++;
    jQuery(".featured" + count % sticky_count).fadeIn().delay(5000);
    jQuery(".featured" + count % sticky_count).fadeOut(callback);
}
```

The `fadeIn` - `fadeOut` effect is working fine till the user navigates to the bottom of the page.  When the user is at the bottom of the page, the entire page scrolls up when the fade switch happens.

You can see this in action at http://www.ronakg.com

Please advice how can I avoid the page scroll.

EDIT: Here's how the HTML code looks like -

```
<div class="featured0">
    ...
</div>

<div class="featured1" style="display:none">
    ...
</div>

...
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is that, coz, nothing there suggests that, to prove the point, comment out the line `jQuery(document).ready(featured_block);` so it looks like this `//jQuery(document).ready(featured_block);` then scroll at the bottom, if the page jumps up, ur problem is not coz of fade in/out its else where, otherwise, you could try to use return false on featured block and/or callback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try giving the containing element of the blocks that fade in and fadeout a static `height:` attribute with CSS.

Wrap `<div id="featured">` block with another div.

```
<div id="rotator" style="height: 340px;">
    <div id="featured">
     ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens in that case is, the featured blocks fade-in fade-out at different locations and not in place.  I am using `style="display:none"` to hide the other blocks when site loads for first time.

Comment: Ah. The blocks would then of course need to be set to `position: absolute;` so they all fade in and out in the same spot.

Comment: `position: absolute` did the trick. However I had to adjust other elements accordingly as the existing structure was relative in nature.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `<a>` with href iqual to "#", just put return false; in the end of your featured_block function that should solve the problem.